# Use center of entire object as pivot point in edit mode (2.8)

Tags: edit-mode

I know how to set the pivot point to the center of an object in Object mode.

But in Edit mode, as soon as I select a group of vertices (or edges or faces) the pivot moves to the center of the selected items.

How do I keep the pivot point in Edit mode the same place as it is in Object mode?

Selecting Pivot Point - Active Element does not work. I know I can use 3D cursor but then how do I ***easily*** set the 3D cursor to the same place as the Object's pivot point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the mesh has any knowledge of its object's pivot point in Edit Mode.. so to put the transform pivot at the object origin, that would be, (with 'Pivot' set to 'Cursor'),

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to Object Mode
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > 'Cursor to Selected'
- <kbd>Tab</kbd>  back again.

I find it's pretty unusual, though, that I don't want my pivot at the center of some edge, face, loop, or somesuch.. in which case *that* can be selected, and the Cursor sent to Selected in Edit Mode.